# Why is Nobita's school suddenly on top of a mountain?

Tags: doraemon

In the *Doraemon* movie *Three Visionary Swordsmen*, it was shown that that the school is at the top of the mountain:

[image]

But isn't the school supposed to be at ground level? You could say that maybe the film's creators specifically put the school on top of a mountain for just that movie. But earlier in the film, when Nobita was helped by the old man in the mountain, his school was not on the mountain but on ground level:

[image]

In this scene, his school is clearly at ground level. So why, at the end of the film, is it suddenly at top of a mountain?

Comment: There is no answer for this question? Perhaps the team Doraemon is destroyed and so in the end of the film, Nobita and Shizuka are in the dream created by the Demon king?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know. In the movie, Doraemon showed that by pressing a button on the gadget, they can exchange their dream and reality, and to make it like before, he has to press the button from the remote. But his mom pressed that button again and Doraemon forgot to press the button from the remote, so some things were exchanged and distorted, so the school was at the top.